# Highcharts: Horizontal labels don't fit the space. How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

As You can see in the image below, the horizontal labels don't actually fit the space they have. I would like to cut off the labels that don't fit and prevent them from overflowing.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: You can try `tickInterval` for `xAxis`. For example `tickInterval = 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 365` will set it to 1 year.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Columns with rotated labels](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels/grid).

Here is an example they used in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/):

```
// highcharts config object
...
xAxis: {
    categories: categoryList,
    labels: {
        rotation: -45,
        align: 'right',
        style: {
            fontSize: '13px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    }
},
... // More configs
```

You can change the rotation of the labels so they should *hopefully* fit side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many ticks, and labels are too long, so I advice to:

- use [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickInterval) and increase a range between ticks
- rotate labels by [rotation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.rotation)
- increase [maxStaggerLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.maxStaggerLines) or adapt [staggerLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.staggerLines)